# how to install API on project that generated by "yo @microsoft/sharepoint"

Tags: reactjs, sharepoint

- Create new folder.
- run "yo @microsoft/sharepoint",(react choosen as JS framework) to
  create project(HelloWorld web part works fine ok).
- run "npm install --save youtube-api-search" api installed fine.

Now api reference added to HelloWorld.tsx file as seen below;

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { css } from 'office-ui-fabric-react';
import styles from './HelloWorld.module.scss';
import { IHelloWorldProps } from './IHelloWorldProps';

import YTSearch from 'youtube-api-search';
//youtube-api-search package exist in "node_modules";

export default class HelloWorld extends React.Component<IHelloWorldProps, void> {
  public render(): React.ReactElement<IHelloWorldProps> {
    return (
      ...
    );
  }
}
```

the error I see in console;

> [09:45:42] Error - typescript -
>
> src\webparts\helloWorld\components\HelloWorld.tsx(6,22): error TS2307:
>   Cannot find module 'youtube-api-search'.

I also used this api in another project which includes react only.Whats the problem here ?

Comment: Could you try "npm install"  ?

Comment: @AungSatt I did it, its same

Comment: How did you setup? Have you done according to this link? https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/spfx/web-parts/get-started/build-a-hello-world-web-part

Comment: @AungSatt only diffirence is he selected No Javascript whereas I selected React rest is same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html, TypeScript resolves `.ts`, `.tsx` and `.d.ts` file. The `youtube-api-search` package has only a `.js` file which cannot be resolved. So TypeScript reports cannot find module.

There are 2 ways you can try:

1. Create a `youtube-api-search.d.ts` file for the package in the `typings` folder, and put the definitions inside.
2. Use `const YTSearch = require('youtube-api-search')` instead.